# JOIN single attribute with multiple table and merge result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would join my table notifications with 2 different tables, let me present a similar example.

Notifications:

```
ID | player_id | item_id | ....
```

Basket player's items

```
player_id | item_id | note | points | rebounds
```

Soccer player's items

```
player_id | item_id | note | match | goal
```

IMPORTANT: all the player ids are unique, the soccer players are in the format 1******** and the basket players are in the format 5********. so also all the couples player_id - item_id are unique.

The result should be a table like this:

```
id | player_id | item_id | note | attr1 | attr2
```

where in "note" there is a note of both kind of players and "attr1" is filled by points or match depends on the player type (same type. INT)

Moreover, the items can be joined with tables SOCCER_ITEMS and BASKET_ITEMS where there are information about the item itself. This JOIN can create duplicated rows because the item_id is not unique between the 2 tables and so a basket item can be joined with the info of a soccer item, creating issues.

is it possible to collect data in the way presented in SQL? I'm writing the code in PHP (don't know if it is useful or not)

Comment: Seems like you just need to explicitly choose the columns in your `SELECT` clause instead of selecting everything with `*`. Can you share the query you tried?

Comment: the tables above are examples but the query is something like:

`code` 
SELECT n.id, n.player_id, n.item_id, b.note, s.note
FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN soccer s ON s.player_id = n.player_id AND s.item_id = n.item_id
LEFT JOIN basket b ON b.player_id = n.player_id AND b.item_id = n.item_id
 `code`

RESULT:
 `code` n.id | n.player_id | n.item_id | b.note | s.note  `code`

2 column for the different "note" columns for example, instead of one that could contains all the results

Comment: In attr1 do you want the column points or match and in attr2 the column rebounds or goal  and so on depending on the type of player?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT n.id, n.player_id, n.item_id, 
       COALESCE(s.note, b.note) note,
       COALESCE(s.match, b.points) attr1, 
       COALESCE(s.goal, b.rebounds) attr2
FROM notifications n 
LEFT JOIN soccer s ON s.player_id = n.player_id AND s.item_id = n.item_id 
LEFT JOIN basket b ON b.player_id = n.player_id AND b.item_id = n.item_id
```

Comment: Thank you @forpas, it can partially solve the problem. in that way the NULL columns are avoided but there still be the possible duplication issue due to the JOIN with the items tables.

Comment: @SWeC What is items tables?

Comment: there 2 other tables that I'm LEFT JOIN with the notifications and they are the reason why some result rows can be duplicated:

SOCCER_ITEMS:
`ID | item_name | some attr`


BASKET_ITEMS:
`ID | item_name | some attr`

The issue is due to the ID that can be the same in the 2 tables. Right now I've solved changing the starting value of both tables for the AUTOINCREMENT ID from a different point that has a big interval between the 2 tables. But I'm looking for a possible solution to avoid this work around.

Comment: The query in my answer is about the question as you originally posted it. If you have anew requirement you can post a new question.